# Is there a tool that can convert C# Linq statements to java?

Tags: java, linq

I know that Java has no LINQ equivalent, but is there a tool (preferably free) that can make suggestions on how to convert a C# LINQ statement to Java statements?

The purpose of this question isn't to find *alternatives* to LINQ, but rather to find a tool that can make *suggestions* on how to convert a LINQ statement to Java.

Discussion of alternatives has been hashed to death on SO and SO does not need another question related to alternatives. However in my research I was unable to locate any mention of a tool that can ease the transition of LINQ to Java.